# Mysql странно работает со строками из пробелов

Tags: mysql

1) `SELECT SUBSTR(' ',1,1)='';`

Такой запрос выдаст ответ 1, а не 0, как кажется интуитивно.

2) `CREATE TABLE symbols (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT, ch  CHAR(1));
INSERT INTO symbols (ch)
VALUES (' ');`

(a) `SELECT * FROM symbols WHERE ch='';`
Ответ будет: id = 1, ch=''

(b) `SELECT * FROM symbols WHERE ch=' ';`
Ответ будет: id = 1, ch=''

(c) `SELECT * FROM symbols WHERE ch='   ';`
Ответ будет: id = 1, ch=''

3) Функции RIGHT(), SUBSTR(), LOCATE() тоже ведут себя подобным нечевидным образом.

4) Замена в примере (2) типа поля CHAR на VARCHAR не меняет странного поведения Mysql.

Может есть какие-то нюансы в настройке конфиг-файла, использовании COLLATE, 
которые позволят работать с пробелом ровно тем же образом, что и
с прочими символами?

P.S. MySQL 5.7, кодировка таблицы utf8, конфиг почти стандартный.

Comment: Самый яркий и простой вариант запроса, иллюстрирующий обнаруженную странность: `SELECT ' '='';` - количество пробелов в примере может быть любым..

Comment: Перед каждым значением строковым поставьте BINARY и тогда сравнение будет происходит строго. `SELECT BINARY SUBSTR(' ',1,1)= BINARY '';` Аналогично во всех следующих примерах. При этом сама ситуация мне вот кажется надуманной - когда и для чего человеку может понадобиться сохранять строку из одних пробелов в базе? Придумайте ситуацию хоть одну разумную.

Comment: Например, при парсинге

Comment: Существенное значение, конечно же, имеет пример 2. В нем BINARY использовать нельзя. Иcпользование COLLATE utf8_bin не приводит к желаемому результату. Добавление слова BINARY в определение поля ch - тоже.

Comment: Возможно сбил с толку, написав "перед каждым". Только в конечных значениях в самом условии where:  `SELECT * FROM symbols WHERE BINARY ch= BINARY '';
SELECT * FROM symbols WHERE BINARY ch= BINARY ' ';
SELECT * FROM symbols WHERE BINARY ch= BINARY '   ';` все примеры корректно отрабатывают.

Comment: При парсинге... Всё же приведите пример, скорее всего это одна из многих задач, которую в принципе не нужно решать на стороне БД.

Comment: У меня дают NULL все варианты: `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS symbols;
CREATE TABLE symbols (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, ch CHAR(1));
INSERT INTO symbols (ch)
VALUES (BINARY ' ');
SELECT *  FROM symbols WHERE BINARY ch = BINARY ' ';`

Comment: Парсить средствами СУБД не принято, но хранить в СУБД результаты парсинга очень даже удобно. Более того, обрабатывать несколько сот вариантов последовательностей из условно "пробельных" символов по множеству правил контекстной зависимости уже будет и удобнее, и быстрее на СУБД.

Comment: Извиняюсь, недоглядел. Действительно, там само значение "пробел" не сохранилось в базу. [Вот что пишут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32723272/how-can-i-store-a-space-character-in-a-mysql-char-field). Т.е., как раз всё-таки хоть само по себе изменение CHAR на VARCHAR Вам вначале ничего не дало - это всё же нужно сделать. Именно чтобы была возможность хранить отдельно пробел. В сам INSERT добавлять BINARY не нужно будет. `INSERT INTO symbols (ch) VALUES (' ');`

Comment: Да, так и есть. Спасибо вам большое. Вот этот вариант работает корректно: `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS symbols;
CREATE TABLE symbols (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, ch VARCHAR(1));
INSERT INTO symbols (ch)
VALUES (' ');
SELECT *  FROM symbols WHERE ch = BINARY ' ';`

Answer (score 1):

Подводя итог из комментариев:

1. В поле CHAR не сохраняется пробел. [Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32723272/how-can-i-store-a-space-character-in-a-mysql-char-field) предлагают в качестве решения заменить CHAR на VARCHAR(1).
2. [Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947581/select-trims-spaces-from-strings-is-this-a-bug-or-in-the-spec/1947694#1947694) советуют добавлять BINARY

   ```
   SELECT * FROM symbols WHERE BINARY ch = ' ';
   ```